# Prolog - Counting specific elements in list of lists

Tags: prolog, append, nested-lists

I have a list 'a' in Prolog.

```
a = [].
```

I have to insert to 'a' another list 'b'

```
b = [bottle].
```

The final result has to be like this:

```
a = [[bottle]].
```

The build-in function *append/3* seems to only concatenate two lists.

`append([item1,item2],[item3,item4],Ans)` gives us `Ans = [item1,item2,item3,item4]` but I need

```
Ans = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].`
```

Can you please help me with this task, I am completely noob in prolog.

Comment: Tokens in lowercase are *not* variables, but constants, hence `a = []` can not be true. `A = []` can. You can just wrap it in another list, so if `B = [bottle]`, you construct `A = [B]`.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I am using ":- dynamic" in order to make them changeable. a([ ]), b([bottle]).

Comment: But I did not know about wrappings, thank you!

Comment: _I am using ":- dynamic" in order to make them changeable. a([ ]), b([bottle])._ This is not how it works. These are facts. It means the empty list has attribute `a` and the list `[bottle]` has attribute `b`. You want a predicate `transform(InList, OutList) :- ...`